# How can I set an entity type within a dto [NestJS]?

Tags: node.js, service, nestjs, dto

I don't even think I've got a proper question so I apologize greatly.

I am consuming a 3rd party API and to update or create records, one of the fields is the entity type.

For example, here is my `CreateOrganizationDTO`:

```
export class CreateOrganizationDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    description: "The entity type. Only 'organization' is allowed.",
    example: "organization",
  })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  readonly @type: string;  <-- this 
  ...
```

I'm not sure how to properly handle the `@` character. I've tried different versions of `'@type'` or `['@type']`. Clearly, neither are correct. I'm also not sure how to send that data through my service. For example:

```
// MyService.ts

 const {name, @type, active} = updateOrganizationDto;

 organization.name = name;
 organization.@type = @type;  <-- not going to work :(
 organization.active = active;
 ...
```

What is the proper way to "escape" this `@` throughout my application? Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: you can't use `@` in variable name in JS. Event tho you can pass the name as string to `@ApiProperty`, I'd say: don't use `@` :p

Comment: btw read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#accessing_properties)